Formatting a geographical STBuffer output to reduce length of the returned Latitude and Longitude string
I am using the geography datatypes in SQL server to output a string of longitude's and latitude's  with a set distance (1 meter in this instance) from a input longitude and latitude.
DECLARE @g geography  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('point(-0.124663 51.499840)', 4326)    

select 
    replace(replace(replace(@g.STBuffer(1).ToString(),'POLYGON ((',''''),'))',''''),', ',''',''') 

I am using the replace formatting on the select statement to format the string so it can then be used in a where clause of another SQL statement to allow me to select any values in another table.
The geography statement outputs the following string:

'-0.12465280384915144 51.499846347274094','-0.12465331513696513
51.499846651882976','-0.12465384975647235 51.499846940466881','-0.12465440641972776 51.499847212330586','-0.12465498378568056 51.499847466819169','-0.12465558046340523 51.499847703319517','-0.12465619501545253 51.499847921261889','-0.12465682596131217 51.49984812012125','-0.1246574717809797 51.499848299418524'

This is a list of Longitudes and latitude as a comma separated list. This issue I am having is the string that is being outputted has a longer scale for each number than the resultant set of data that I am looking up against.

Postcode data from Doogal.co.uk primarily has a scale of 6 i.e. (-2.242851 57.101474)
Postcode data from Office for National Statistics primarily has a scale of 6 i.e. (-2.239768 57.089299)

If I manually change the string output to the below, my second SQL query finds the relevant data, so I need to find a way to set each value returned in the geography statement to have a scale of 6.

'-0.124652 51.499846','-0.124653 51.499846','-0.124653
51.499846','-0.124654 51.499847','-0.124654 51.499847','-0.124655 51.499847','-0.124656 51.499847','-0.124656 51.499848','-0.124657 51.499848'


This sounds very fishy, on a day with a lot of fishy questions already. What kind of query are you writing that makes more precise values return less rows than less precise ditos. How does your "second query" looks? Why not use the geometry built-in methods to find whatever data you're looking for

The data in the second query is looking against values that only have a scale of 6 i.e. 6 values after the decimal, the geography query returns a scale of 15 i.e. 15 values after the decimal place, the string value with a scale of 15 doesn't match the data that has a scale of 6

I get that, but it shouldn't matter. Unless you're directly joining the values on each other which you shouldn't do when working on geometry data anyway. Once again, how does the second query look? Did you look into GEOGRAPHY.STWithin and other functions?

"I am using the replace formatting on the select statement to format the string so it can then be used in a where clause of another SQL statement to allow me to select any values in another table." That's almost certainly the wrong thing to do. You should break out the values using GENERATE_SERIES and STGeometryN or STPointN and some CROSS APPLYs. How about you construct some sample data (full CREATE and INSERT statements) and your full queries showing the issue.

"format the string so it can then be used in a where clause of another SQL statement". That seems very strange to me. Why not do declare @buffer =geography::STGeomFromText('point(-0.124663 51.499840)', 4326).STBuffer(1);  select * from yourTable where yourGeom.STIntersects(@buffer) = 1. That is, why are you marshaling back and forth between a text representation of the disc? I agree with others' assessment here that your reasoning of "I need a specific precision" seems suspect. For your known values, check the distance between them and the buffer using STDistance().
